# Keras does not work when using 10 epochs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

This is absolutely bizarre, but when I run my Keras CNN model using 10 epochs, each epoch (including the first one) gives me a .333 accuracy (I have 3 categorical classes.) Using any other number of epochs seems to work fine, giving me ~.55 accuracy after the first epoch and continuing to grow to ~.9 accuracy. The model is defined as follows:

```
import os
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dropout, Flatten, Activation, GlobalMaxPooling2D, PReLU, LeakyReLU
from keras.layers.core import Flatten, Dense, Dropout
from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling2D
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

input_shape = (405, 270, 3)
batch_size = 16
epochs = 15

# training_directory = os.getcwd() + '\DataSubset\TrainImages'
# test_directory = os.getcwd() + '\DataSubset\TestImages'
# num_classes = 70
# train_samples = 27992
# test_samples = 7000

training_directory = os.getcwd() + '\SmallDataSubset\TrainImages'
test_directory = os.getcwd() + '\SmallDataSubset\TestImages'
num_classes = 3
train_samples = 9578
test_samples = 2415
target_shape = (405, 270)

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(training_directory, target_size=target_shape, batch_size=batch_size)

test_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255).flow_from_directory(test_directory, target_size=target_shape,
                                                                        batch_size=batch_size)


def create_short_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='sigmoid'))

    return model


model = create_short_model()

print(model.summary())

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                              steps_per_epoch=train_samples // batch_size,
                              epochs=epochs,
                              validation_data=test_generator,
                              validation_steps=test_samples // batch_size)

plt.plot(history.history['acc'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_acc'])
plt.title('model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Has anyone else encountered this issue / does anyone know of something I may be missing?

Comment: and you're sure this is reproducible? not just unlucky random numbers once?

Comment: Ya, I've run the model about 10 times with 3 epochs, each time giving me similar results and I've tried 5 times now at 10 epochs, even tried restarting my computer several times. Always had the .333 accuracy (+/- ~.005). I went back to 3 epochs and it worked fine, tried 15 epochs, and it worked fine.